# Webdriverio tests on chrome fails but runs fine on edge

Tags: webdriver-io

Where I run my webdriverio tests on chrome I receive below error -

```
Execution of 1 workers started at 2023-10-25T05:38:48.485Z

2023-10-25T05:38:48.538Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onPrepare hook
2023-10-25T05:38:48.541Z INFO @wdio/utils: Setting up browser driver for: chrome@stable
2023-10-25T05:38:48.545Z INFO @wdio/utils: Setting up browser binaries for: chrome@stable
2023-10-25T05:38:48.548Z INFO webdriver: Downloading Chromedriver v118.0.5993.118
2023-10-25T05:38:48.866Z WARN webdriver: Chromedriver v118.0.5993.118 don't exist, trying to find known good version...
2023-10-25T05:38:49.268Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Shutting down spawned worker
2023-10-25T05:38:49.536Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Waiting for 0 to shut down gracefully
2023-10-25T05:38:49.539Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: shutting down
Error: Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1540:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:959:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:743:12)
Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1540:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:959:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:743:12) {
  code: 'UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY'
```

However run on the MSedge is absolutely fine.
I have the below configuration -
"@types/mocha": "^10.0.3",
"@types/webdriverio": "^5.0.0",`your text`
"@wdio/local-runner": "^8.20.5",
"ts-node": "^10.9.1",
"typescript": "^5.2.2"
Node version - 18.16.0